# d3 svg text-shadow for edge / internet explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, d3.js, svg

Hello I was wondering if there was a possible way to get text-shadow to work with edge / internet explorer on a d3 sunburst graph.

Things i have tried within the text code is

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#000000,direction=45);
```

and

```
filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=1, offy=1);
```

*which didn't seem to work at all when added into the css or an attr to this*

```
var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(partitioned_data)
    .enter().append("text")
    .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)
    .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
        return d.x + d.dx / 2 > Math.PI ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        var angle = (d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
        var differenceSpacing = 0;
        if (angle > 90) { differenceSpacing = 1.41; }
        else { differenceSpacing = 1.39; }

        return "rotate(" + angle + ")translate(" + (d.y * differenceSpacing) + ")rotate(" + (angle > 90 ? -180 : 0) + ")"

    })
    .attr("dx", "1") // margin
    .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align  
    .text(function (d, i) { return d.name })
    .attr("class", function (d) { if (d.depth === 3) { return "finalLayersText"; } else if (d.depth === 1) { return "beginningLayersText"; } else { return "middleLayersText"; } })
    .style("fill", "white")
    .style("font-family", "Arial")
    .style("font-size", "small")
    .style("color", "white")
    .style("text-shadow", "0 0 10px Black")
    .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
    .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
    .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc);
```

So I was curious if there was a way to add a text-shadow within this small part of the javascript where the text is generated.

Thanks

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/cpbotha/5200394 is a good example of how to do it. IE10+ supports SVG filters. No solution for IE9 and below.

Comment: This actually solved my problem. Would you like to make a post so I can accept it as the answer ?